# Downsampling Issue with Conv2D Layer in AWS SageMaker Notebook

Tags: tensorflow, tensor

I am encountering an issue with the downsampling in the Conv2D layer when running my code on an AWS SageMaker Notebook. The code runs fine on my local machine and in Google Colab, but I am facing this specific problem in the SageMaker environment.

Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
# Define the model
inputs = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(inputs)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2))(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
outputs = Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
```

The error message I am receiving is:

```
ValueError: One of the dimensions in the output is <= 0 due to downsampling in Conv2D. Consider increasing the input size. Received input shape [None, 28, 28, 1] which would produce output shape with a zero or negative value in a dimension.
```

I have tried increasing the input size, but the issue still persists. It is worth mentioning that I am using the TensorFlow framework and the code runs without any problems on other platforms.

I would greatly appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this downsampling issue specifically in the AWS SageMaker Notebook environment.